# Access modified variable inside onClick

Tags: android, variables

in the code below , how do i access the variable inside the onClick method? I am trying to take the url which is saved upon clicking the save button. However , since it's not declared before onCreate , when i try to use it , there is a red line. How do i make the variable global so that I can acccess it from another method ?

The variable I am trying to access [urlStr] :

```
   package sp.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class DetailForm extends Activity {
    private EditText name = null;
    private EditText author = null;
    private EditText url = null;
    private EditText duedate = null;
    private RadioGroup category = null;
    private BookHelper helper = null;
    private Button save = null;
    private Button delete = null;
    String urlStr;

    private String bookId = null;


    CheckBox chkbox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_form);

        helper = new BookHelper(this);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.author1);
        duedate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.duedate);
        url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
        category = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.category1);

        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

        delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
        delete.setOnClickListener(onDelete);

        bookId = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
        if (bookId != null) {
            load();
        }


    }

    private void load() {
        Cursor c = helper.getById(bookId);
        c.moveToFirst();
        name.setText(helper.getName(c));
        author.setText(helper.getAuthor(c));
        duedate.setText(helper.getDue(c));
        url.setText(helper.getUrl(c));

        if (helper.getcat(c).equals("Action")) {
            category.check(R.id.action);
        } else if (helper.getcat(c).equals("Mystery")) {
            category.check(R.id.mystery);
        } else if (helper.getcat(c).equals("Thriller")) {
            category.check(R.id.thriller);
        } else if (helper.getcat(c).equals("Romance")) {
            category.check(R.id.romance);
        } else if (helper.getcat(c).equals("Horror")) {
            category.check(R.id.horror);
        } else {
            category.check(R.id.others);
        }
        c.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        helper.close();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onDelete = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (bookId == null){
                return;
            }

            else {
                helper.delete(bookId);
                bookId=null;
            }

            finish();
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String nameStr = name.getText().toString();
            String authStr = author.getText().toString();
            urlStr = url.getText().toString();
            String dueStr = duedate.getText().toString();
            String catStr = "";

            switch (category.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.action:
                catStr = "Action";
                break;
            case R.id.mystery:
                catStr = "Mystery";
                break;
            case R.id.thriller:
                catStr = "Thriller";
                break;
            case R.id.romance:
                catStr = "Romance";
                break;
            case R.id.horror:
                catStr = "Horror";
                break;
            case R.id.others:
                catStr = "Others";
                break;
            }

            if (bookId == null) {
                helper.insert(nameStr, authStr, dueStr, urlStr, catStr);
            } else {
                helper.update(bookId, nameStr, authStr, dueStr, urlStr, catStr);
            }
            finish();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.gotourl){
            Intent i = new Intent(DetailForm.this,webactivity.class);
            i.putExtra("url",urlStr);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

web activity

```
package sp.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class webactivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webview;
    private String url = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://" + url);
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }
    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
  {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: Keep `String urlStr`, and `EditText url` as global variables, i.e. before `onCreate`

Answer (score 1):

Declare `String urlStr` and `EditText url` just below the line inside the class extending activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {   
   String urlStr ;   //here
   EditText url;
```

Comment: Hi , I've tried it , but when i change  i.putExtra("url",urlStr); , i realised that it's value inside is null. What i am trying to do is that , upon onClick , String urlStr will hold a value . I am trying to send it inside an intent to another activity. However , when i declare urlStr before onCreate , it holds a null value. What i want to access is the modified value inside the onClick.

Comment: Give these variable some value where you have declared them,and see what is being passed..... just a little bit debugging

Comment: i tried putting String urlStr = "www.google.com" and it does execute that url. However , it is not executing the url which i saved inside onClick.

Comment: You want to start your activity from menu option, right?

Answer (score -1):

As MysticMagic said, make it global. But I think it should be a little bit more explained with an example. In Your class do it like this:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   //make it global here
  private String urlStr=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //initialize the string here

          urlStr = url.getText().toString();
        }
    });
}
```

and then in Your onOptionsItemSelected, check if the string is valid before using it:

```
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.gotourl){
        //check if urlString is not null)
       if(urlStr!=null){
        Intent i = new Intent(DetailForm.this,webactivity.class);
        i.putExtra("url",urlStr);
        startActivity(i);
      }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

In Your second activity, get the value like this:

```
   //like above, make it global:
    String url =null;


       //and get the value from intent
       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          if(extras !=null) {
         url = extras.getString("url");
        }
```

Comment: Hi , i believe the urlStr declared on top is null. However , how do i use the urlStr declared inside :

 private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) ?

Comment: if You make it like I showed You with String urlStr = null; , You just let the system know, that it is used later when it is initialized. You can also write String urlStr; (without =null). If You want to use urlStr, You can only use it if it is not null, that´s why I explained it with check if urlStr is not null inside the onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: If I am understand this the right way, the user put some url inside an EditText and have to confirm this with a buttonClick, right?

Comment: Correct . I managed to execute the code , but the value of urlStr seems to be null. Any suggestions how I access the variable inside the url and send it over ? :x

Comment: Ok, why do You think the urlStr is null? Do You get problems in Your DetailActivity or do You just get null if You try to get the String inside Your webActivity?

Comment: hmm the reason i believe it's null , is because when i send it over to the webactivity through the intent and open up in my app , it shows "http://null" .

Comment: then You got problems by passing the string. I don´t think that this string is null. Ok, do the following: first make a Log inside Your onClick in the DetailActivity after the urlStr is initialized and check the logcat output. Also, change the code in Your webactivity and do it like I have shown on how to get the "url" string in Your webActivity.

Comment: hmm . i might have misinterpreted your comment mate . When I did as you showed me , the code didn't execute . if i understand correctly , if the urlStr is null , it's not supposed to send the intent over right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So, put in the url, press the save button, and then the optionsMenu button, this should work, if there is no other issue in Your code..

Comment: hmm maybe i have not explained fully man . it does work when i put into the url , save and options menu too . but problem is , i want it to only take the url that i have saved , because right now , if i erase the edittext field , input any url and click optionsMenu without saving , it redirects to the new url . i want it to only take the url which i have saved.

Comment: but, I see that You call finish() inside the onSave()...why have You done this? It would be better to finish this activity only if the other one is surely opened....

Comment: I can´t get an idea why this behaves like You explained. If You don´t save, then the old url should be still existing. There must be anything that saves the url from the editText...

Comment: i believe that is the case right now . the getUrl executes any url that isn't even saved when it should be reading the old url...